# Updating a table on button press

Tags: sql, oracle, button, sql-update, oracle-apex

I am trying to make a simple APEX function that allows the user to click a button on the page which corresponds to a team. I am using page processes once the button is pressed to increment the point value for the specific team by 1. An example of one of the processes is:

```
UPDATE teams

SET number_of_points = number_of_points + 1

WHERE team_colour = 'Blue';
```

This piece of SQL is executed on the page submit and when the button is pressed.

Unfortunately, no matter which button is pressed, all of the page processes are fired and all teams gain when point. How can I make it possible for the process to only effect the team for which the button corresponds to.

Comment: Hi. Here what is happening, when you having a click event it is not trigerring a particular update. You nheed to specify particular tag for each color button. Please mention some code to get clear idea.

Comment: It is because of the fact when you are trigerring the update button it is not happening for single 'COLOR'. You need to specify some sort of tag on each colored button so that particular update should happen.

Comment: Please tell us how you have defined your buttons in apex (name in particular, what action), and your process(es) (in particular, did you define a when-button condition or a regular condition)